# Collect user data on wifi only using google analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics, wifi

I am using google analytics for my android app. I was wondering is it possible to collect user data when he is on wifi. I mean I want to capture all the events but receive them when user is whn user is on wifi? I guess I can do it by dispatching manually, but I am more interested to know if there is a configuration that GA does this automatically?